# Can this nonconvex optimization problem be tranformed into a convex problem?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization

I’m trying to solve the following optimization problem.

Minimize M subject to

$0=t_{1,1}\prec t_{1,2}=t_{2,1}\prec t_{1,3}\prec t_{2,2}=t_{3,1}\prec t_{3,2}\prec t_{2,3}\prec t_{3,3}=M$,

$t_{j,k}=a_j x_k+b_j$,

$a_j,b_j,x_k≥0$

where $c\prec d$ means that $d-c\geq1$.

I know that this problem is not convex because of the nonlinear equality constraints. Is there a change of variables that will make this problem convex? If not, what other techniques might be used to solve this problem?

Comment: Really $c\prec d$ is used to compare vectors or matrices, this means that $d_{ij}-c_{ij}>0$, I would like to know if it is a writing error in your post.

Comment: Other questions, if you want an answer you must say that it is everything that shapes your question, for example, What is $ M $? If $ M $ is a function, in terms of what variable is expressed?
In short, you should improve the writing of your post.

Comment: What are the variables of the problem here? In particular, why do you say the equality constraints are nonlinear?